# Выполнять декодированный код

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

Хочу использовать авто обновляемый код, в планах было заранее кодировать код через base64, заливать на сервер, а на клиентской стороне декодировать этот код и выполнять, но получаю ошибку `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, как и каким образом мне надо кодировать\декодировать данные?
(не рабочий код)

```
decoded = base64.standard_b64decode(b'ZGVmIHByaWludCh4KToKICAgIHByaW50KHN0cih4KSkKZm9yIHggaW4gcmFuZ2UoMTApOgogICAgcHJpaW50KHgp')
print(str(decoded)+'\n\n\n')
eval(decoded)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выполнения полноценного кода на Python используйте встроенную функцию `exec()` вместо `eval()`.

Eval позволяет вам лишь получать результаты **выражений**.

В отличие от `exec()`, eval не хранит переменные, функции и прочие объекты в памяти.

```
import base64

decoded = base64.standard_b64decode(b'ZGVmIHByaWludCh4KToKICAgIHByaW50KHN0cih4KSkKZm9yIHggaW4gcmFuZ2UoMTApOgogICAgcHJpaW50KHgp')
print(str(decoded)+'\n\n\n')
exec(decoded)
```

Вывод:

```
b'def priint(x):\n    print(str(x))\nfor x in range(10):\n    priint(x)'



0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Спасибо, перепутал функции